# Can I delete my iCloud email account?

Tags: icloud

I signed up with iCloud and I see that there is an @me.com email account associated with my account.  I don't have any interest in using email with iCloud - I use gmail for email.  Is there a way to remove email from my iCloud account all together?

Perhaps I am being paranoid, but I am afraid there might be security risks from having another email account around that might be used for Apple account change notifications.  Since I never check that account I wouldn't know if something seemed wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems to be impossible to get rid of this account.

What I've done is:

- Connect to my [iCloud account](https://www.icloud.com/) (with my Apple ID, the same for the App Store and others).
- Go to Mail.
- In `Preferences` (top right), choose `rules…`
- Add a rule to redirect all emails received at my @me.com address to my main email.

It can take several minutes to work, but I don't lose anything like that.

Comment: That sounds like a good suggestion.  I will also forward me email from there.  Thanks!

Answer (score -3):

go to Settings, mail, then Icloud, and turn off Mail

Comment: Perhaps this answer would be more helpful (and, in turn, get a slightly better vote count) if you explained exactly what effect this has and how it fixes busyspin's problem. In general, answers are better if you explain *why* they work.