# How can I completely delete an iCloud account

Tags: iphone, icloud, email

I've come to the conclusion that I don't want to use my current iCloud account any longer, primarily because I used to register to various online services with it which won't stop to send me mail.

Is there a way to delete an iCloud account from Apple's servers?

Comment: See also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59812/can-i-delete-my-icloud-email-account for a way to automatically delete mails from specific senders.

Comment: It's always wise to have a disposable email address or two for signing up to things you don't necessarily ever want to hear from again.

Comment: In clear text, for the future, ->create a account (with fake name ect) with mail.com. Then set up a garbage email that you now can use with anything but do not really care about it. That email you can give to anyone or use to sign up to questionable sites. Do not be surprised if you get lots of spam, but since it is not your regular email who cares.

Answer (score 1):

From my brief searching through the Apple discussion sites, it looks as though you can't actually delete an iCloud account!

Here are some links to some posts I've read regarding this:

- ['How to Close an iCloud Account '](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3453048?start=0&tstart=0)
- ['closing my icloud account '](https://discussions.apple.com/message/21048604#21048604)
- ['How can you close an icloud account?'](https://discussions.apple.com/message/20059238#20059238)
- ['Upgraded to Yosemite, signed up for iCloud and an now want to close iCloud account. How do I do that? '](https://discussions.apple.com/message/26991200#26991200)

According to the answers from people with fairly high credentials for the above questions, it isn't possible.  The only option you have is to disconnect your device(s) from iCloud and just stop using it unfortunately.

The reason you provide for not using the iCloud account though is because of bombardment of emails from services you have subscribed to.  I suggest a 'block sender' use on your email client whatever that may be, or alternatively [the option suggested by @patrix](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/59812/can-i-delete-my-icloud-email-account).  Also, most of these types of emails I have found have an 'unsubscribe' link at the bottom of their emails, so you should also probably look for that on some of these emails.

Hope this is of some help!